# simple ajax request to load external json file

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm learning ajax.... I am trying to make a basic request from a json file, which is in the same folder as my index.html, but for some reason it says undefined :( I can see the error is on the variable people, but I can't catch why it's undefined....

html:

```
<div id="personName"></div>
```

javascript:

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); //it holds the ajax request
     xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { //callback 
             if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
               var people = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);//it takes the string from the response and it converts it in a javascript object
               console.log(people);
                 for (var i=0; i<people.length; i += 1) {
                      var htmlCode = "<p>" + people[i].name + "</p>";
                 }                
                      document.getElementById('personName').innerHTML = htmlCode;
     } else {
         console.log(xhr.readyState);
     }
 };
 xhr.open('GET', 'addresses.json');
 xhr.send();
```

addresses.json:

```
{ 
    "people":  [    
            {
                "position"     : "1",
                "name"         : "Familia Molina Fernandez",
                "streetType"   : "C/",
                "streetName  " : "Nuria",
                "streetNumber" : "40",
                "floor"        : "",
                "flat"         : "",
                "zipCode"      : "08202",
                "city"         : "Sabadell",
                "state"        : "Barcelona",
                "country"      : "Spain"
            },
            {
                "position"     : "2",
                "name"         : "Familia Astals Fernandez",
                "streetType"   : "Avda/",
                "streetName  " : "Polinya",
                "streetNumber" : "61",
                "floor"        : "1",
                "flat"         : "1",
                "zipCode"      : "08202",
                "city"         : "Sabadell",
                "state"        : "Barcelona",
                "country"      : "Spain"
            }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas?

Cheers!!!!

Comment: `people.length` there's no length property to call

Comment: undefined is the error!!

Comment: ohmg O__O I am not trying to call any property.... I am trying to loop through the whole array length :S Oux wait a minute.... I'm realising now.... length is just for strings... isn't it? what should I use then? :S

Comment: Objects doesn't have length ; but `people` **is** an object. Use `for (var key in people) { console.log(people[key]); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `console.log(people);` and take a look at the object to which your variable refers.  (*Hint: it's not what you think it is!*)

Your variable `people` refers to an object with only one attribute named "people".  That attribute is an array.  So with that JSON structure, your code could be written:

```
var data = JSON.parse(...)
var people = data.people;
```

(alternatively, I might redesign the JSON and remove the extra level of indirection: just encode the array itself without wrapping it in an object that contains nothing else)

Comment: dsh, thank you! now it's displaying at least one of the names. However, as I said.... I'm learning... so it sounds a bit too complicated. Saying redesign the JSON you mean deleting "people:" ?

Comment: Yes.  Instead of `{"people": [...]}` to have `[...]`  Then the data structure would match the code you posted.